# VMware revert script

Tags: vmware

All,

I'm looking to write a web front-end that has the necessary capabilities to revert a specified virtual machine to a default snapshot. Im specifically using VMware ESX.  I'd like to keep folks from getting into Vcenter and having management-like access. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want the VIX API: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/